# Git clone error “HTTP code 405 from proxy after CONNECT”

Tags: git, proxy, http-status-code-405

I'm working in a office behind a corporate firewall. My system is Windows 10 Pro, I have set up a the proxy configuration using Git Bash:

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://corporateproxy.example.com:8080
$ git config --global https.proxy http://corporateproxy.example.com:8080
```

After that the `.gitconfig` file looks like:

```
[user] 
    name = myname
[http] 
    http://corporateproxy.example.com:8080
[https] 
    http://corporateproxy.example.com:8080
```

I am trying to clone a repository using Git Bash as follow:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxxx.git
```

But this throws the following error:

```
Cloning into 'xxxxxx'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxxx.git/': Received HTTP code 405 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I have tried to unset and set back againg the proxy configuration both in Git and in the console but still having the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You know I'm seeing the same error and can't figure out what the issue is. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Hello @C0D3 I spoke with the proxy administrator and I was able to do it. I do not really know what they did.

Comment: Ok, thanks for getting back to me. I'm trying to get some help from my IT department as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

405 means Method Not Allowed error

Check your proxy settings, ports or you could try to use ssh method like this

```
ssh://git@xxxxx.xxx:7999/apps/xxxx.git
```